# Make a font awesome stop blinking or hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, font-awesome

Please I will be glad if someone can help me, I have create two buttons to control this `font-awesome` icon. The buttons should:

1. Turn the blinking off or on.
2. Hide or display the icon.

Thank you so much.

```
<i class="fa fa-chevron-right text-success Blink"></i>
```

CSS

```
.Blink { animation: blinker 0.1s cubic-bezier(.5, 0, 1, 1) infinite alternate; }
@keyframes blinker { from { opacity: 1; } to { opacity: 0; } }
```

Comment: **When**? while on hover?

Comment: @Ramesh. No while button is clicked.

Comment: @Wolff. I'm sorry i couldn't get anything to practice with on Google. But if you can help, there'll never be a duplicate of this question. I'll practice with it and become good.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but this is the thing you need to do according your requirement.

```js
$("button").click(function(){
    $(".Blink").toggle();
});
```

```css
.Blink {
     animation: blinker 0.1s cubic-bezier(.5, 0, 1, 1) infinite alternate;
}
 @keyframes blinker {
     from {
         opacity: 1;
    }
     to {
         opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class="fa fa-chevron-right text-success Blink">s</i>
<button type="button"> Toggle</button>
```

Toggle between hide and show for all  elements.

For more information:- [jquery toogle](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp)

Comment: I have tried your answer but still remains the same

Comment: Wow.. I am so sorry. It works perfect. I was not connected to the internet so the ajax library wasn't loaded.

Comment: I am happy you got your answer bro :-)

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible for me to have this button control this icon from another page?

Comment: no you can not control button click event from another page

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is the requirement you are looking for ,use this as your reference

**HTML**

```
<button id="onOROff">
OFF
</button>
<button id="showORhide" value="Hide">
Hide
</button>
<i class="fa fa-chevron-right text-success Blink"></i>
```

**CSS**

```
.Blink { animation: blinker 0.1s cubic-bezier(.5, 0, 1, 1) infinite alternate; }
@keyframes blinker { from { opacity: 1; } to { opacity: 0; } }
```

**Script**

```
$("#onOROff").on('click',function(){
$("#onOROff").text(this.innerText=='OFF'?'ON':'OFF');
if(this.innerText=='ON')
$('.fa-chevron-right').removeClass('Blink');
else
$('.fa-chevron-right').addClass('Blink');
});
$("#showORhide").click(function(){
$("#showORhide").text(this.innerText=='Hide'?'Show':'Hide');
    $(".Blink").toggle();
});
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wy9h1660/)

> Note: this is jquery dependent solution make sure we have use it only once in a js references

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks it works perfect. I wish I could vote just yet.

Comment: But. Is it possible for me to have these buttons control this icon from a different page?

Comment: it dependents based on your design , if buttons are in Master layout then it works ,else if both are completely different pages it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

Here are the code changes you need.

HTML:

just give a id to i tag as follows and introduce two new buttons for toggling blink and display

```
<i id="blink" class="fa fa-chevron-right text-success Blink"></i>
<button onclick="toggleBlink()">Toggle blink</button>
<button onclick="toggleDisplay()">Toggle display</button>
```

CSS:

include the following class

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

Just make sure you incuding this css after including font awesome css because the font awesome class has display: inline-block property

JS:

Include below click handlers for buttons

```
var blinkIcon = document.getElementById("blink");

function toggleBlink() {
    blinkIcon.classList.toggle("Blink");
}

function toggleDisplay() {
    blinkIcon.classList.toggle("hide");
}
```

make sure you are including this script after DOM has loaded.

Comment: I am so happy im getting very many options as answers to pick from. I wish to know if it's possible to have these buttons in a separate page from the icon and still control it

Comment: @Guy Randalf This solution is without using JQuery.

Comment: Alright thanks.. But I updated my last comment. Care to take a look please?

Comment: What do you mean by separate page, separate file?

Comment: No page. For example: I have control.html with the buttons and another page icon.html where the icon is. I want to control the icons in icon.html from the control.html page.

Comment: Okay separate file

Comment: you can have separate file for JavaScript and link in html file. but you cannot separate that html content like that since you want to load in same page